# Quickest to import data from database into Excel

Tags: c#, excel

I am creating a C# plugin for Excel and have noticed that there seems to be a many ways that you can actually import data from a database into a sheet in excel.

I am targeting Excel 2010 and wondered whether anyone has already done this research and knows what the quickest way to load the data is?

I can already guess that anything breaching the COM boundary is going to be slow so I have to minimize that. So I can stick all the data into one 2d array and load it that way. Loading 0.5million rows with 10 columns takes around 5.5seconds (assuming I have all the data in the array already). I don't know whether that is good or bad.

...but like I said there are alot of ways to get the data in and I would like to use the fastest.

Comment: Whether it's good or bad depends on your needs. Not on anything external. Decide what your requirements are, then find a tool that meets those requirements. By the way, [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) is well known for speed and ease of use.

Comment: @mason - my requirements are to load large datasets into Excel as quickly as possible. So far I can do 0.5million rows in 5.5seconds using COM. The requirement is to beat that

Answer (score 0):

Create a database query in the Excel sheet, specifying a connection string, target range and query string. Have the query executed from within Excel.
See http://www.dicks-clicks.com/excel/ExternalData3.htm for an example.

Comment: execution by excel is the fastest way? really? i am ... surprised.

Comment: Excel query within a range is a built in object. Execution is natively executed by Excel without reoeated calls through COM.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried SQLBulkCopy ?

Comment: What is your specific question?